# Strange behavior of emulators on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, emulation, windows-10, mobile-emulator

After some OS updates on Windows 10, emulators in Visual Studio 2015 started to behave strange. First of all, the rendering issue where the screen has a soft blur. I don't know if you can see it in the picture below but it is not as sharp as it used to be:

[image]

Additionally, rotating screen is not working as it should be. If I rotate screen to the right it rotates to the left and half of the screen is black. And so on.

[image]

This is the the screenshot of the 6-inches screen:

[image]

I've tried to uninstall all the latest updates, reinstall emulators, reinstall whole Visual Studio but with no avail. The problem persists. I wonder if this has something to do with Hyper-V ?

Comment: I am currently struggling with the same issue. I am running Visual Studio Community 2015, Version 14.0.24720.00 on a Windows 10.

Comment: The same problem. After installing (clear) Windows 10 1511 I see the same pictures on VS 2013 WP 8.0/8.1 SDK and Emulator 10.0.10586.0 does not start on VS 2015. 
The strange thing is Microsoft does not produce any activity conсerning this elementary detected bug... I am in full frustration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by restoring Windows 10 to an earlier build.

Comment: Did you solve this issue on current Windows 10 build?

Answer (score -1):

Please Restart windows while pressing Shift key. This will throw a blue screen with options to choose to go advanced and then you see options for uninstalling last update etc.
I simply uninstalled the last feature update and windows returned to normal. 
Go for it.